# run service that listen on android calendar events

Tags: android

i need to create a service that stay running and listen to calendar events, when an event occured i take the event Id and do actions based on this event, is that possible?

thanks

Comment: yes, it can be possible using Alarm API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it is very much possible please go through with the below link :

http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/02/android-basics-alarm-service/

Comment: hii but this dont listen and trace the occuring of events from the calendar,look this is specific what i want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893660/calendar-events-and-alarmmanager-service-in-android , if you can help